# Right way to get Cloud SQL connection(s) in Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

When you create SQL Connection for a Cloud SQL instance that has Public IP in `Cloud Run Service`, Cloud Run creates a socket file in directory `/cloudsql/<PROJECT-NAME>:<DB-INSTANCE-REGION>:<DB-INSTANCE-NAME>`.

In order to not hardcode `PROJECT-NAME` and `DB-INSTANCE-REGION`, I query Container MetaData Service and get `project-id` and `region`. This all works fine as long as my DB Instance is in the same region as my Cloud Run Service but will not work if the DB Instance is in a different region then Cloud Run Service.

Is there a way to query Container MetaData and get associated connections or is there a better way to achieve this instead of hardcoding DB Instance region?

Comment: Have you considerd to setup this string part of your deployment as environmental variable?

Comment: I certainly have but there are use cases where my cloud run service may get deployed to multiple regions but the associated database may not or may get deployed in the same region as service but at a later stage. I am trying to do this without rebuilding the container as rebuilding the container will make me go thru the entire lifestyle of approvals and such.

Comment: You don't need to rebuild the container for ENV changes. Whenever you deploy your CR service to a region, "at deploy" you set the ENV to cover the whole/cloudsql/ thing

Answer (score 1):

To provide dynamically values to your runtime environment, you have 2 solutions:

1. Either use [environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables) as proposed by Pentium10
2. Or use [arg value](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/containers#configure-entrypoint) to provide to your container